# Take Average of an Array using Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, average

I'm trying to create a program that will take a user input, input that data into an dynamic array, and then recursively finds the average. The first part of my code works. This allows the newly created array to be passed to the method.

```
 public static void main(String args[])
{
    
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    double runningTotal = 0;
    
    int classSize;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      
    System.out.println("Please enter the class size: ");
    classSize = keyboard.nextInt();
    int newClassSize[] = new int[classSize];
    
    for (i=0; i < newClassSize.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the grade of the user at: " + (i + 1));
        newClassSize[i] = keyboard.nextInt();   
    }
    
    findAverage();
    
    
    for (i=0; i < newClassSize.length; i++){
                
        
        sum = sum + newClassSize[i];
    }
                    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newClassSize));
            
    
keyboard.close();
    
}
}
```

This is where I'm getting confused and confusing myself however. How would I pass the newly created array to the findAverage() method? I would then need to also have that be saved to an accumulator and then devided. Is there a better way to do this? This is my current findAverage() method but I'm confusing myself on my implementation.

```
public double findAverage(int classAverage, int baseCase, double runningAverage)
{
    runningAverage = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    
    if (newClassSize.length - 1 > baseCase)
        runningAverage = newClassSize.length;
        
    
    return findAverage();
    System.out.println("The class average is " + classAverage);
    
}
```

Comment: Is there a restriction to use an array or can you use ArrayLists?

Comment: Hi Richard, I believe there is a minor restriction to not use ArrayList but at this point, I'm banging my head against the wall just to get this working. Did you know of  way with ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understood your question correctly but heres how to do it below.
The basic idea is that when the index reaches the length of the array in the
recursive function that's the base case. So all you have to do is add to the sum at each index point in the array, and just keep passing in the updated index and sum into the recursive function.

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int newClassSize[] = {1,2,3}; // User Input let say

        
        double average = findAverage(newClassSize);
        System.out.println(average);
    }
    
    
    public static  double findAverage(int[] arr){
        // Avoid division by zero error
        if (arr.length==0){
           return 0;
        }
        return findAverageHelper(arr,0,0);
    }
    
    
    public static  double findAverageHelper(int[] arr, int index,int sum){
        if (index==arr.length){ // Base Case 
            return (double) sum/arr.length;
        }
        // Increase index and add current value at index to sum
        return findAverageHelper(arr,index+1,sum+=arr[index]);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: If this helped you can you accept the answer by pressing the green arrow. That will help me. No problem and have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks @carlosdafield

I see you added one here. Is it okay if I try to explain the program and tell me if my logic is correct?

findAverage(newClassSize); invokes the method and passes the date from array data from newClassSize to the method. 

Now I'm a bit confused after that part, is the findAverageHelper only being used to pass data to the findAverage() method? It seems that this is where the main recursion is taking place, then after findAverageHelper finishes, it returns the data back to findAverage() which returns the data to the main program

Comment: Yeah thats correct it looks more clean when you just pass the array in to a function instead of an array and two numbers. Thats all it does. Yeah your logic sounds good to me

Comment: Ah I see @carlosdafield.
So you're effectively using the first recursive method at findAverage() as the stop case which is only invoked at the end of the function? But the helper method is the actual workhorse of the array?